# Android - shell utility to perpetually disable headset device?

Tags: shell, services

I have an HTC Desire HD device that has some schmutz in the wired headset jack, and the output from 'logcat' (http://pastebin.com/cNZC8Wwc) shows it vacillating between 'Headset=true' and 'Headset=false', when there is in fact nothing present in the headset port.

```
I/HeadsetService( 1977): Headset=false; Bluetooth=false
I/HeadsetService( 1977): Selected configuration: speaker
I/HeadsetService( 1977): Headset=true; Bluetooth=false
I/HeadsetService( 1977): Selected configuration: headset
V/WiredAccessoryManager( 1746): Headset UEVENT: {SUBSYSTEM=switch, SWITCH_STATE=0, DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/switch/h2w, SEQNUM=12164, ACTION=change, SWITCH_NAME=Headset, SWITCH_TIME=9817830244064}
V/WiredAccessoryManager( 1746): newName=Headset newState=0 headsetState=0 prev headsetState=1
```

This makes the handset almost impossible to use for calls without workarounds.

I understand that this is a common problem and that it has been addressed by more than one application in the Market store.  Still, those applications I have tried have not worked correctly to eliminate this problem.

I can't physically clean the port at the moment, and I would like do do this 'manually' via the shell.

Isn't there a straightforward way to do this?  I have tried with the activity manager and package manager search and try to get and set relevant data, but I haven't seen a way to say something like:

```
    localhost / # am kill HeadsetService
    localhost / #
```

-which does not stop the flip-flopping device detection.

Can I just echo something to a file like '/sys/devices/virtual/switch/h2w/state' and then use chattr to make it immutable?  Is that even the right file for the wired audio headset?

EDIT:  This doesn't work:

```
    localhost / # chattr +i !$
    chattr +i /sys/devices/virtual/switch/h2w/state
    chattr: reading flags on /sys/devices/virtual/switch/h2w/state: Not a typewriter
    localhost / #
```

Comment: Why not just clean the port?

Comment: I'd like to know how one does so (disables such a device) at the OS level.

Anyway, I have tried to do so without taking the thing apart.  I don't currently have access to a tool with which to take it apart.

Comment: That's very probably not possible*. The root cause is identified so I'd suggest you just fix the root of the problem (dirt) and not apply band aids in the wrong place (trying to disable it at the OS level). (* It may of course be possible using mad haxor skillz, but i don't think it'll be worth researching and applying them to this type of problem)